# How can I recover the chat after closing a BlueJeans session?

Tags: bluejeans

I use [BlueJeans](https://www.bluejeans.com/) for videoconference on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. When I close a BlueJeans meeting, after closing it, how can I recover the texts sent in the chat box?

Comment: Check the pockets within the Blue Jeans for the notes!!! j/k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### After closing a BlueJeans meeting how can I recover the texts sent in the chat box?

You can't. It's a feature request that is being worked on:

> This feature is currently being worked on, but we do not have an ETA as to when it will be released. Once the ticket has an estimated ETA assigned, I will update this thread.

Source [Would like to be able to capture the chats after the call ends | BlueJeans Community](https://community.bluejeans.com/bluejeans/topics/would-like-to-be-able-to-capture-the-chats-after-the-call-ends)

Comment: is there any progress on this in last few years?

Comment: Is it still the case?

Comment: @TechTurtle No idea. The link in my answer now requires a login.